# Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: default or static interface method used without --min-sdk-version >= 24

Tags: android, scala, sbt

I am getting the following exception while running my android app in the emulator using **sbt android:run**:

```
Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: default or static interface method used without --min-sdk-version >= 24
```

Needless to say that I am using Scala/SBT and totally new to the android arena.

I have tried all the solutions I could find like using the latest version of *guava*:

```
"com.google.guava" % "guava" % "23.2-android"
```

or turning *multidex* on:

```
dexMulti in Android := true
```

This is how my build.sbt looks like:

```
name := "Scala1"

version := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.3"

platformTarget := "android-26"

javacOptions in Compile ++= "-source" :: "1.8" :: "-target" :: "1.8" :: Nil

enablePlugins(AndroidApp)

dexMulti in Android := true

minSdkVersion in Android := "24"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.android.support" % "appcompat-v7" % "24.0.0",
    "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "23.2-android")

// libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
//     "com.android.support" % "appcompat-v7" % "24.0.0"
//     )

// Enable proguard and link it to the config file 'proguard-project.txt'
proguardOptions in Android ++= io.Source.fromFile("proguard-project.txt").getLines.toSeq
```

Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to change both java source and target version in `build.sbt` to 1.7:

```
javacOptions in Compile ++= "-source" :: "1.7" :: "-target" :: "1.7" :: Nil
```

It works like a charm now.